# AngularJS controller communication with nested isolate scope directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

In my AngularJS application, I have to create an accordion with each section containing a slider control. I want both the accordion and the slider to expose APIs to the outer controller, for example:

```
accordion.collapseAll()
accordion.openNextPane()
```

or

```
slider.resetValue()
```

And I would like to be able to do in the controller something similar to:

```
$scope.clickNext = function() {
    $scope.accordion.openNextPane();
};

$scope.clickResetAll = function() {
    $scope.items.forEach(function(item, ind) {
        $scope.slider[ind].resetValue();
        // or:
        $scope.accordion.pane[ind].slider.resetValue();
    });   
}
```

I'm thinking of creating isolate scope directives for the accordion and the slider, with a two-way binding to allow them to expose their methods to a parent controller. The page template would then look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <accordion data="accordion">
        <div ng-repeat="c in collection">
            <accordion-pane>
                <slider data="slider"></slider>
            </accordion-pane> 
        </div>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

But at this point I'm lost in a maze of isolate scopes and limited visibility on children, and it seems that there is no way to access the inner elements from the outer controller. Many solutions I've googled around seem to consider normal to have the directive talking to the controller instead of the other way round, but this seems to break encapsulation.

Any idea on how to do this? What is the correct AngularJS pattern for this problem?

Comment: Yes, this is not very clear. What you could do: use shared service and implement simple Observer pattern there, then subscribe inside directive. Then you could also use native event-system, but this is ugly, avoid it. Another option is you could register inner directive controller on the outer controller via `require` config. One more option is actually to use bindings, one way or two-way could work here, but they are less convenient for calling methods, although possible too. I would probably go with service. Let me know if something is not clear, I could probably post more extended answer.

Comment: Thank you. The service solution removes the dependency between directive and controller, but at the price of creating another external one for both of them, and by using require you're still creating a dependency of the directive on the controller, right? Which is what I'm trying to avoid. Instead, could you explain better what you mean with using one or two-way bindings - as this is precisely what I don't seem to be able to do?

Comment: You could do something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/f48i6b8QehrGnnIGPi79?p=preview, but I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know of Angular 1.5 components, and from what I've read they seem to do what I'm trying to. Unfortunately my solution is in Angular 1.2 - so that's not an option at the moment. I've made a quick hacky directive to expose a directive's isolate scope to the parent controller, maybe I can add it to my question.

Comment: Component is just a simplified directive, you can do the same thing with normal directives too.